# Perl argument switch based on regex

Tags: regex, perl, arguments, pcre

I have a Perl script that takes in arguments.  When I had single value arguments, the following code sufficed:

```
                    switch ($ARGV[0]) {

                    case "--cmd1" {
                            $action = "cmd1";
                    }


                    case "--cmd2" {
                            $action = "cmd2";
                    }
```

Now, I have a case where the command, `cmd3` has a parameter, as in `--cmd3=SOMETHING`.  Since `SOMETHING` can vary, the simple switch/case does not work anymore.  Basically, I need to do a switch/case on the command itself.  I thought I could use a regex with the first matching group being the command and the second being the optional equals.  The following does not work, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
                    $ARGV[0] =~ m/(.*?)(=.*){0,1}/;
                    my $cmd = $1;
                    my $equals = $2;

                    switch ($cmd) {

                    case "--cmd1" {
                            $action = "cmd1";
                    }

                    case "--cmd2" {
                            $action = "cmd2";
                    }

                    case "--cmd3" {
                            $action = "cmd3";
                            print $equals;
                    }
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I figured it out, but I'll give the guy who answered upvotes and accept anyway.  I could not use if because that means restructuring everything.  Here's the solution.

```
                   switch ($ARGV[0]) {

                    case "--cmd1" {
                            $action = "cmd1";
                    }

                    case "--cmd2" {
                            $action = "cmd2";
                    }

                    case m/--cmd3(=.*)?/ {
                            $ARGV[0] =~ m/--cmd3(=.*)?/;
                            $action = "cmd3";
                            print $1;
                    }
```

Comment: Why not use `Getopt::*`?

Comment: Put the possible commands in a dispatch table, using hash keys as the literal command name, and code references as the hash values.  Then after your pattern match, you can say, "`$dispatch{$1}->($2)`"

Comment: Perl's switch is a (deprecated) source-filter hack.  given/when, or for/when are probably better, but I'm mostly in favor of just using a hash based dispatch for something like this.

Comment: @David but how can I put --cmd3 in the hash table?  The argument could be --cmd3=AAA or --cmd3=BBB.  Still the same argument.  I need to split the command based on the equals, but the equals is not always present as in cmd2 and cmd1.  The whole system is already built using switch.  It can not be changed.

Comment: "can not be changed"?  then you can't add extra arguments, can you?  You are going to have to change *something*.  When you do, please remove at least this one instance of using the deprecated and buggy switch().

Comment: What's wrong with switch?  It looks a lot cleaner than writing tons of if\else.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-do-I-create-a-switch-or-case-statement%3f  : "as it's implemented as a source filter, it doesn't always work as intended when complex syntax is involved"

Comment: The syntax is not overly complex and seems to be working just fine for this script.  Switch stays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
my $cmd = "";
my $equals = "";

if($ARGV[0] =~ m/^\-\-cmd1$/){$cmd="cmd1"}
if($ARGV[0] =~ m/^\-\-cmd2$/){$cmd="cmd2"}
if($ARGV[0] =~ m/^\-\-cmd3=(.*)$/){$cmd="cmd3";$equals=$1}
```

Comment: My mistake but the equals on cmd3 is optional.  --cmd3 and --cmd3=SOMETHING produce different results and are both valid.  You can keep the accept though.

Comment: If you go with this and don't mind "hacky", you could easily add this line to capture the other form of `cmd3`: `if($ARGV[0] =~ m/^\-\-cmd3$/){$cmd="cmd3"}`

Comment: There is no need to escape the `-` characters in your regex.  Also, the first two should actually be `if ( $ARGV[0] eq '--cmd1' )` since you are using no regex features.

Answer (score 5):

Why aren't you using [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long)?

Comment: The system was already made with manually parsing out the arguments.  It can not be changed.  I am just adding this additional feature.

Comment: So you could make it use `Getopt::Long`.